# How to convert a list of Open Street Maps (OSM) IDs to geojson to plot on folium?

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, folium

I have searched for my region counties manually and I have now a list of OSM IDs. Example:
https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/4791885 - ID is in this case `4791885`.

I would like to plot this shape in `folium` (to do later on a choropleth map of the population density). I tried downloading manually the xml and then using this library `osm2geojson` but it did not work (`multipolygon member not handled")

```
import folium
boulder_coords = [41.3874, 2.1686]
#Create the map
my_map = folium.Map(location = boulder_coords, zoom_start = 7.5)
geojson = "MY MISSING FILE"
folium.GeoJson(geojson, name="moianes").add_to(my_map)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(my_map)
my_map
```

As mentioned I have a list of IDs e.g. 2417889, 2822130 up to 42 in total so if the solution can handle it efficiently (less manual work) would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I think to download the xml directly from your link will not provide the geometries data of your selected region. My last answer is failed to show the data. However, if you just need to show geojson data from OSM, you can do it. But, you need to store the geojson data in a folder (I put them in "geojson" folder, name the geojson according to the id or something that you preferred)

```
#Create the map
import folium
import codecs
ids=[4791885,2417889] #This will be a place for your ID's list
boulder_coords = [41.3874, 2.1686]
my_map = folium.Map(location = boulder_coords, zoom_start = 7.5)
for id in ids:
    name=str(id)
    with codecs.open('./geojson/'+name+'.geojson', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as data:
        geojson= data.read()
    folium.GeoJson(geojson, name=name).add_to(my_map)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(my_map)
my_map.save('index.html')
```

For retrieving geojson data from OSM, I still do them manually by using [Overpass Turbo OSM](https://overpass-turbo.eu/). Here is what I got:
[the Folium result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFQQv.png)

Comment: Answer works so I upvoted it! I will leave it open as I feel a manual solution is not ideal. I also posted an overpass turbo question for my particular problem but that may be useful to others facing manual work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69950326/open-streets-maps-how-to-query-overpass-turbo-by-a-tag-with-any-value

Answer (score 0):

### Looping through the OSM ID

I think first you can download the xml data according to your ID's list (save it on folder named "xml")

```
# Download the data
import requests
link='https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/'
ids=[479188,2417889,2822130] #This will be a place for your ID's list
for id in ids:
   url=link+str(id)
   r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
   open('/content/xml/'+str(id)+'.xml', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

### Create the Map

Then, you can read the xml file to geojson using [osm2geojson](https://github.com/aspectumapp/osm2geojson) by looping through the ID again to read xml file. Add it as layers on your map.

```
#Create the map
import folium
import codecs
import osm2geojson
boulder_coords = [41.3874, 2.1686]
my_map = folium.Map(location = boulder_coords, zoom_start = 7.5)
for id in ids:
    name=str(id)
    with codecs.open('/content/xml/'+name+'.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as data:
        xml = data.read()
        geojson=osm2geojson.xml2geojson(xml, filter_used_refs=False, log_level='INFO')
        folium.GeoJson(geojson, name=name).add_to(my_map)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(my_map)
my_map
```

Comment: I get an error at line "---> 12 folium.GeoJson(geojson, name=name).add_to(my_map)" saying "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Oh, the adding geojson to map should be in the looping. I've just edited my code

Comment: Issue remains - from the output of osm2geojson it is not clear to me whether the conversion is truly working.